# How was Anton able to get away with these activities while he was being hunted?

Tags: night-watch-cycle

In the book *Night Watch*, during the second story about Maxim,

> who ends up becoming an Inquisitor,

shortly after the events at the Indian restaurant, Anton Gorodetsky is on the run.  He takes the subway, and at the exit, he encounters a Dark One...

> ...whom he kills with his handgun loaded with silver bullets.

He then makes his way up the TV tower where he encounters a Dark One stationed as a sentry...

> ...whom he pulls into the second level of the Twilight and leaves there, whereupon the man gets his fingers stuck in the tower glass, and shortly after falls to, presumably, his death.

In the end Anton discovers that the entire operation...

> ...was planned by Gesar, and not by the Day Watch as Anton had believed.

In light of this, how does Anton "get away with" his actions during that time?  I'm wondering this both from a moral point of view, given his status as a Light One, and from a "legal" point of view vis-a-vis the Treaty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading further in the book, I discovered that Zabulon answers this when he's in Anton's apartment in the third part of the book.  I've read the book before, but I guess this goes by so quickly, I'd forgotten it:

> "So you see, Anton.  Maybe we're enemies.  We are enemies.  Last winter you caused us some inconvenience, serious inconvenience.  This spring you frustrated me again.  You eliminated two Day Watch agents.  **Yes, of course, the Inquisition declared that your actions were committed in self-defense out of absolute necessity** but, believe me—I was not pleased.  What kind of leader is it who can't even protect his own subjects?